# Prevent taps from passing through buttons in XAML/WPF

Tags: wpf, windows, events, xaml, event-bubbling

In my project, I have a large container with a handler for taps. Inside this container, I also have a button. My goal is to handle all taps on the background container UNLESS the user clicks on the button. Unfortunately, when I click on the button, it fires both the click handler on the button AND the tap handler for the container.

Here's some example XAML:

```
<Grid Width="250" Height="250" Fill="Red" Tapped="Container_Tapped">
    <Button Click="Button_Clicked">
        <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Blue" />
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Is there a way to handle the tap event on the button to prevent it from bubbling to the container? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `Container_Tapped` event handler you could check the [RoutedEventArgs.OriginalSource Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.originalsource.aspx). If `e.OriginalSource` is a descendant of your button do nothing.

For that [Visual.IsDescendantOf Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.isdescendantof.aspx) could be helpful.

Comment: It's a good idea. I'm not sure if I'm just not implementing it correctly or if I need to do more -- the original source never seems to be of type Button. But because buttons use content templates, doesn't this mean I could be getting TextBlocks or Rectangles or other elements on my clicks? Am I going to have to walk the tree to see if a button is a parent of my OriginalSource?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a dynamic way to do it in Win RT, without needing to know the exact name of the button (useful if you have a pile of buttons to work with, such as when databinding!)

```
    ' Verify that the sender is not a button (or one of its children)
    If Not e.OriginalSource.Equals(sender) Then
        Dim parentObj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(e.OriginalSource)
        Do While Not parentObj.Equals(sender)
            If TypeOf parentObj Is Button Then Return
            parentObj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parentObj)
        Loop
    End If
```